# How to loop from certain number to certain number in AEM?

Tags: aem

In data-sly-list I can loop through elements as in following examples

data-sly-list: Repeats the content of the host element for each enumerable property in the provided object.However, what if I want to loop through the first 4 elements or from 8th till 10th elements, how to do so?

Here is a simple loop:

```
<dl data-sly-list="${currentPage.listChildren}">
    <dt>index: ${itemList.index}</dt>
    <dd>value: ${item.title}</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<dl data-sly-list="${currentPage.listChildren}">
    <div data-sly-test="${itemList.count > 4 && itemList.count <8}" data-sly-unwrap>
        <dt>index: ${itemList.index}</dt>
        <dd>value: ${item.title}</dd>
    </div>
</dl>
```

You can use either of **count** or **index** variable.